# Absolutely continuous part of $\mu$ wrt $\nu$ as quotient $\lim \mu(A)/\nu(A)?$ as $A$ tend to singleton?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If I have two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ and I want to compute the absolutely continuous part $\mu_a$ of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$, can this be achieved somehow by taking quotients like
$$
\frac{d\mu_a}{d\nu}(x)=\lim_{A \to \{x\}}\frac{\mu(A)}{\nu(A)}.
$$
If this doesn't work does something similar work?
I'm happy to assume $\mu,\nu$ are Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ if it makes any difference.

Edit: Note: Theorem 7.14 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis is exactly that the result holds for $\nu$-a.e. $x$, when $\nu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: See [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/154130/90906) on MO. As pointed out there, this works if the measures are finite on balls and the sets $A$ are balls.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. if your post your comment as an answer, perhaps copying the theorem 5.8.8 from  Bogachev's text volume 1, I'll accept it.